# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeDeprecatedCustomComponents.NavigationExperimental.Navigator')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have installed the react-native-deprecated-custom-components because of the error that it gives me when I run the syntax with import {Navigator} from 'react-native'. When I have changed the syntax it gives me an error that is TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeDeprecatedCustomComponents.NavigationExperimental.Navigator')

I have already tried to change the navigator to NavigationExperimental.Navigator but still the error does exist

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  NavigationExperimental
} from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';
import Movies from './Movies';

const RouteMapper = (route, navigator) => {
  if (route.name === 'movies') {
    return <Movies navigator={navigator} />;
  }
};

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationExperimental.Navigator
        // Default to movies route
        initialRoute={{ name: 'movies' }}
        // Use FloatFromBottom transition between screens
        configureScene={(route, routeStack) =>    Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom}
    // Pass a route mapper functions
    renderScene={RouteMapper}
  />
);
  }
 }
```

the result is that it will display the current data that i have

Comment: Shouldn't it be `configureScene={(route, routeStack) =>    NavigationExperimental.Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom}`? Double check all your namespaces/classes. `console.log(NavigationExperimental)` and make sure the required classes/functions/properties exist that you're trying to access.

Comment: I still got the same error sir

Comment: Did you read the second part of my comment?